Pole and Residue of $\frac {1}{\sin^3(z)}$ at $z=0$
Let
$$
f(z) = \frac {1}{\sin^3(z)}
$$
This function has poles at
$$
\sin(z) = 0 \implies
z = n\pi \text{, } n \in \mathbb{Z}
$$
For simplicity let's take the pole $z=0$
We can write
$$
f(z) = \frac{\phi(z)}{z^3}
\\
\phi(z) = \frac{z^3}{\sin^3(z)}
$$
Now $z=0$ is a pole of order $m=3$ because
$$
\lim_{z \to 0} \phi(z) = 1 \neq 0
$$
But the hard part is computing residue
$$
Res_{z=0}\text{ }f(z) =
\frac 1{(m-1)!}
\lim_{z\to 0}
\phi^{(m-1)}(z)
$$
Directly differentiating $\phi(z)$ is not a good idea, you get a messy expression
Another idea is to consider
$$
f(z) = \frac{\phi(z)}{z^3}
\implies \phi(z) = z^3 f(z)
$$
But this is a dead end too, differentiating results in a hairy hard to deal with expression
The last resort is computing Laurent series of $f(z)$ around $z=0$
Since $z=0$ is a pole of order 3 we have
$$
f(z) =
\frac{b_3}{z^3} + 
\frac{b_2}{z^2} + 
\frac{b_1}{z} +
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n
$$
where $b_3\neq0$
$$
f(z) = \frac 1{z^3}
\left(
b_3 + b_2 z + b_1 z^2 + 
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^{n+3}
\right)
$$
In other words we have
$$
\phi(z) = z^3 f(z) =
b_3 + b_2 z + b_1 z^2 + 
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^{n+3}
$$
The expression is clearly analytic at least at $z=0$
Thus we have Taylor expansion for $\phi(z)$ around $z=0$
Here I'm puzzled, how can $\phi(z)$ be Taylor expanded around $z=0$ even though $\phi(0)$ is even not defined
Does taking $\phi(0)=\lim_{z\to0}\phi(z)=1$ makes any difference?
This whole scenario also happens when taking original $f(z) = \frac {\cot(z)}{z^2}$
Or maybe all this is wrong and $z=0$ is an essential singularity of $f(z)$
Help!
